# Why do I get an import error when a child file is trying to access a parent file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory, pytest

My directory is structured like this

```
>project
 >tests
    >test_to_json.py
 >app.py
 >x.db
```

in my `test_to_json.py` I want to access a class from `app.py`

How would I import it? I've tried `from ..app import myClass` but that gives me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It would help if you included the exact error message.  Saying "it doesn't work" does not give us much detail.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. The error is ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Convert `project` into a [package](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `..` relative pathing in python. That specific type of relative python is simply not allowed. `.` is allowed, though. The resolution for this problem is usually done by converting your project into a python package.

Extensive tutorials for doing so can be found [here](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html), but I will give an example of how to convert your project into a package.

### Step 1

The new file structure should look like this:

```
>project
  >tests
    >__init__.py     #Note this file
    >test_to_json.py
  >__init__.py       #Note this file
  >setup.py          #Note this file
  >app.py
  >x.db
```

### Step 2

Write your `setup.py`.
Here is an generic `setup.py` that should work for your project:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='project_package', #the name of your desired import
    version='0.0.1',
    author='An Awesome Coder',
    packages=find_packages(),
    description='An awesome package that does something',
    install_requires=[], # a list of python dependencies for your package
)
```

`find_packages()` looks for all the `__init__.py` files in your package to identify submodules.

### Step 3

Install your package. In the folder with your new `setup.py`, run `pip install -e .` This will install your package on your computer, basically adding the files to your python system path.

### Step 4

From any python terminal on your computer you should now be able to import your package using the `package_name` you specified.

```
import project_package
from project_package.app import myClass

myClass()
.
.
.
```